# i want to update only one field in django using model Forms

Tags: html, django, modelform

*modelForms*

```
class OrderForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'

*views.py *
def update_order(request,pk):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = OrderForm(instance=order)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST,instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('admin')

*midels,py*
    class Order(models.Model):

    STATUS = (
        ('Return', 'Return'),
        ('Out for delivery', 'Out for delivery'),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
        ('new order', 'new order'),
        ('hold', 'hold'),

        )
    order_id= models.CharField(max_length=120, blank= True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True , choices=STATUS, default='new order',blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True,blank=True)
    receiver_name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    receiver_address= models.CharField(max_length=200)
    receiver_phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    condition= models.IntegerField(blank=True,default=0,null=True)
    order_date1 = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    delivery_cost = models.IntegerField(default=60,null=True,blank=True)
```

*html page*
{{form.status}}
*i have tried {{form.status}} this but it not working but if i user all {{form}} is showing me the all fields and its working but i don't want to show all fields in html page *

Comment: Show the OrderForm too. It has the Meta.fields option.

Comment: i have use fields =  __all__

Comment: mentio that filed name in fields = 'xyz' in forms here , which one filed you are going to update

Comment: @RedPerson That's your problem. If you use `fields = '__all__'`, you get all fields in there.